# Hide dropdown button

Tags: itext, textfield

I'm creating a TextField as so:

```
            iTextSharp.text.pdf.TextField fieldCombo = new iTextSharp.text.pdf.TextField(stamp.Writer, realArea, placeHolder);
            fieldCombo.Choices = (new string[1] { "" }).Concat(attribute.Values.Select(x => x.Value.Code)).ToArray();
            iTextSharp.text.Font bold = iTextSharp.text.FontFactory.GetFont(iTextSharp.text.FontFactory.HELVETICA, 9f, iTextSharp.text.Font.BOLD);
            fieldCombo.Font = bold.BaseFont;
            fieldCombo.FieldName = Guid.NewGuid().ToSafeString();
            fieldCombo.FontSize = 10f;
            fieldCombo.TextColor = new iTextSharp.text.BaseColor(System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(255, 6, 97, 50));
            fieldCombo.Options = iTextSharp.text.pdf.BaseField.EDIT | iTextSharp.text.pdf.BaseField.VISIBLE_BUT_DOES_NOT_PRINT;
            stamp.AddAnnotation(fieldCombo.GetComboField(), page + 1);
```

From the first time the field is focussed, a very generic grayish down arrow appears on the document, positioned next to my value. Even if the field is unfocussed, this arrow stay visible.

Can I get rid of this combo box button when printing the document?

Comment: *From the first time the field is focussed, a very generic grayish down arrow appears* - this may well depend on the PDF viewer you use. Which one do you use?

Comment: I see it in Foxit. But on any viewer, like those included on phones on which I develop, the button is always there. It takes different look, but it's there.

Comment: The appearance of annotations (e.g. form fields) is up to the PDF viewer. Even if an appearance is provided by the PDF, the viewer can ignore it completely. Thus, you may probably achieve an appearance of your choice on one or a few viewer versions; but you won't achieve achieve it for all. That's why I asked for your viewer.

Comment: I was seeing an hypothetical 'hide' combo box button feature more like an Acro Form behavior than a style proper to the viewer. I don't have a lot of visual experience with interactive PDF so I can't say that in the past I've ever seen a combobox with a button that disappears once unfocussed or that is just invisible. I'll search more.